# Monitoring URLs accessed from a network

Tags: networking, proxy, url

I am looking for a good solution (on-premise or cloud-based) which can provide some visibility into the web sites (URLs) being accessed by workstations/laptops within my company's network? We do not have a proxy server for outbound internet access.

Comment: if you need to understand where they go, you need a place where you can "listen" to their behaviour, how are you connected to the internet

Comment: Logs would be saved in the router, assuming it's capable. I doubt a domestic router would be capable, but a corporate router would likely do that by default - mine does.

Comment: @skv We are using a Cisco RV series business router that directly connects to our ISP.

Comment: @Tetsujin We have tried to use NetFlow data, but that is limited to outbound IP addresses. There is no easy way to map these to domains that were accessed.

Comment: ah, I've never used NetFlow itself, though my gateway might be using it under the hood. Mine gives me data for in & out-bound & resolves IP addresses for me.